# Opto coupler schematic

Tags: schematics, opto-isolator

I am analyzing following circuit, but I am not getting its flow.

In the following schematic SW1 is coming from controller and connected to opto coupler ( cathode of LED ) and J4B is connected to heater.

Please explain me its operation and when Mosfet will conduct?[image]

Answer (score 3):

its simple, the controller generate a square wave in S1, (probably its at VCC level at the beginning) your circuit U9 (Optocoupler) will work when the diode inside it is conductive at low level, so the transistor Q1 is operational (ON) and you can enable the heater.
The LED D11 is conductive when the transistor Q1 is ON.

Answer (score 2):

When SW1 connects the LED cathode to ground, the LED lights up (inside the optocoupler, in infra-red). The light causes the phototransistor to conduct. This raises the gate voltage of the MOSFET, and the MOSFET conducts. Current will flow through the MOSFET from the 24V supply, via the heater.

So, to turn the heater ON, connect SW1 to GROUND. Note that this must be the ground of the Vcc power supply, which may be separate from the ground of the 24V supply.

Comment: The ground of Vcc must be separated from the ground of +24V to avoid U9 short circuit.

Comment: What is function of R34 and when Q1 conducts, what will be it's gate voltage?

Comment: @codo No, the grounds can be connected. U9 will not be short-circuited.

Comment: @Techknowlogic R34 is used to switch the MOSFET off by ensuring that the gate voltage goes to zero when the phototransistor is off. You can work out the gate voltage by considering R33 and R34 as a voltage divider.

Comment: @Techknowlogic its a pulldown MOSFET resistor.

Comment: @JohnHonniball At my knowledge, the opotcoupler ground input must be separated from the Optocoupler ground at the output! (galvanic isolation)

Comment: @codo It's usual to have separate grounds, otherwise there's no need for an optocoupler. But it's not mandatory.

Comment: see the link of wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation

Comment: @codo Yes, that's correct. But the circuit will still work if the grounds are connected. Nothing will get shorted. But then you will have no galvanic isolation, so you might as well not use an optocoupler.

Comment: @JohnHonniball You're quite right, but you still risk the ground loop if you connect the two grounds: http://saaubi.people.wm.edu/TeachingWebPages/Physics351_Fall2009/Week8/Chapter8_OptoIsolation_GroundLoops.pdf

Comment: @codo Yes, you're right. It's absolutely usual for the grounds to be separate. But it's not mandatory and the optocoupler will not get shorted.

Comment: When Opto coupler LED will conduct? When SW1 is at LOGIC O or 1 ?

Comment: @Techknowlogic As I said in my answer, at ground. That's logic zero.